# Восстановление базы данных

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Удалил базу данных. Можно как-то восстановить? Без бекапов?
Не знаю, попробовать зацепки или восстановление базы MySQL из бинарных логов.
Что-нибудь в том духе, больше никаких зацепок нет у меня!

Comment: У меня был дом, сгорел...<br>
можно как-то восстановить?..<br><br>
Вот вы написали что-то в этом духе...

Comment: Есть такой анекдот:

Первый: Как в *nix восстановить случайно удаленный файл ?

Второй: Нет ничего проще - из бэкапа.

П: А у меня нет бэкапа...

В: Радуйтесь, это значит файл Вам не нужен !

(видимо следует сейчас заметить, что 1.) это подразумевается  ДОС-программист, в ДОС можно было попытаться найти удаленный файл на диске).

Comment: Восстановление базы MySQL из бинарных логов, можно тут использовать   ? И как ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут есть инфа, поэтапно рассказано

[История восстановления базы MySQL из файлов (InnoDB)](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/mysql/125358/)

и

[Восстановление базы MySQL из бинарных логов](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/mysql/50064/)

вообще восстановить просто файлы баз данных с помощью спец. проги на компе.